# Is there a method in selenium that encompasses find_element_by_name and find_element_by_id?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to replace:

```
driver.find_element_by_name('my_name')
driver.find_element_by_id('my_id')
```

by something like:

```
mysteps = [('name','my_name'), ('id', 'my_id')]
for step in mysteps:
    driver.find_element_by_XXX(step[0], step[1])
```

which seems more pythonic to me. This would allow me to make a beautiful class!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've got it, but I'm still leaving the question up in case it's useful.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

mysteps = [(By.NAME,'my_name'), (By.ID, 'my_id')]
for step in mysteps:
    driver.find_element(*step)
```